# Android BufferedReader.Read(CharBuffer target)

Tags: android, arrays, char

I have a problem with the `BufferedReader` in Android.

I am sing a server to receive and send data. For the receiving, I use a `BufferedReader` and the method `Read(CharBuffer target)`.

As long as I receive simple `Strings` there is no problem. But if I receive a sequence like:

> 0xEB 0x58 0x35 0x3F 0x82 0x3A 0xCC 0x66 0x6F 0x6C

...every `Byte` which has the highest bit set appears in the `CharBuffer` as `0xFFFD`.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Sounds like encoding/endianess issues http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: To solve the problem I decided to get the data from the socket directly using `client.getInputStream().read(bytebuf)` where `client`is the socket object receiving the data.